# Specifying validation for specific form in some page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a javascript function that validate a popup form before submit it. Unfortunately it's created to handle one popup form per page only.
In my case, i have two different popup forms, so i want to specify what to do and also for which one.

```
$.fn.goValidate = function() {
var $form = this,
    $inputs = $form.find('input:text');

var validators = {
    email: {
        regex: /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/
    }
};
var validate = function(klass, value) {
    var isValid = true,
        error = '';

    if (!value && /required/.test(klass)) {
        error = 'This field is required';
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        klass = klass.split(/\s/);
        $.each(klass, function(i, k){
            if (validators[k]) {
                if (value && !validators[k].regex.test(value)) {
                    isValid = false;
                    error = validators[k].error;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return {
        isValid: isValid,
        error: error
    }
};
var showError = function($input) {
    var klass = $input.attr('class'),
        value = $input.val(),
        test = validate(klass, value);

    $input.removeClass('invalid');
    $('#form-error').addClass('hide');

    if (!test.isValid) {
        $input.addClass('invalid');

        if(typeof $input.data("shown") == "undefined" || $input.data("shown") == false){
           $input.popover('show');
        }

    }
  else {
    $input.popover('hide');
  }
};

$inputs.keyup(function() {
    showError($(this));
});

$inputs.on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    $(this).data("shown",true);
});

$inputs.on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
    $(this).data("shown",false);
});

$form.submit(function(e) {

    $inputs.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('.required') || $(this).hasClass('invalid')) {
            showError($(this));
        }
    });
    if ($form.find('input.invalid').length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#form-error').toggleClass('hide');
    }
});
return this;
};
$('form').goValidate();
```

I'm pretty sure that it's all about this line:

```
$('form').goValidate();
```

Let's say that the first form id is form_1 and the second form_2.
What should i put in this line?
Something like this i guess:

```
 $('form['form_1]').goValidate();
```

Hope it was clear, thanks !

Comment: You will then write `$('#form_1').goValidate();` Assuming `form_1` is id of the first form.

Comment: You rock!!! what a quick response, thanks a loot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use form `id` to target your form.

ex. if your first form has id `form1` then you can write.

```
$('#form1').goValidate();
```

and same as second one.